# disposeWhenFinished() causes crash on API 21

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

following onDestroy method is making my app crash when running on API 21 (for example when i rotate the screen):

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) {
        mHelper.disposeWhenFinished();
        mHelper = null;
    }
}
```

The method is from the IabHelper class which Google provides in its in-app-billing tutorial.

```
/**
 * Disposes of object, releasing resources. If there is an in-progress async operation, this
 * method will queue the dispose to occur after the operation has finished.
 */
public void disposeWhenFinished() {
    synchronized (mAsyncInProgressLock) {
        if (mAsyncInProgress) {
            logDebug("Will dispose after async operation finishes.");
            mDisposeAfterAsync = true;
        } else {
            try {
                dispose();
            } catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                // Should never be thrown, because we call dispose() only after checking that
                // there's not already an async operation in progress.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {package name}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: packagename.util.IabHelper$1@3bf48617
```

I couldnt find a solution for this, which wonders me, because this method is needed for in-app billing.

Comment: Have you tried     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

You need to release your IabHelper before `onDestroy()` super call or some where in `onPause()` ensuring that your activity will finish using `isFinishing()` method, because there is no guarantee that the code after `onDestroy()` super call will be excuted.

Disposal should be done before activity context unbinds from the play billing service. You are getting that message because you might be hitting the case when your app has released the connection the service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That didnt work, but i found out that the reason is a bug in the IabHelper method provided by google.

This line: if (mContext != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);

Must be changed to this: if (mContext != null && mService != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);